# How should I attach my data to my Backbone Views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have my views correctly displaying fake information and so I am now trying to apply asynchronus data loading to retrieve actual data. The problem is that I am uncertain about how I should go about this. Should I create AJAX calls myself? Should I use the Socket API? Should I use the built in REST api (and how to do so asynchronously)? The server side handler is still unimplemented so as far as how the server serves up the data, that is completely flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i doubt your own ajax calls is what is needed here...

i can't tell about sockets however i know it is possible and a solid idea depending on your app.

i have been using the default REST functionality and it works well for me,
a small example as how I would do it,

to make it less complex i will just act as if it is from page load, instead of using routers and all.

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        var v = this;
        this.model.bind("change", function(e) {
            this.render();    
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.el.empty();
        this.el.text(this.model.get('name'));
    }
});

var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/api/myModel", // change to your server code... 
    defaults: {
        name: "john"
    }
});

$(function(){
    var m = new myModel({}); // dummy model
    var v = new myView({ model: m, el: $('#myDiv')});
    v.render();

    m.fetch(); // takes the url of the model or collection and fetches it from the server side ...

});
```

if you want to test what the fetch would do, you can for try this code from your console, (or add it to the jquery document load function:

```
m.set({ name: 'peter' });
```

this changes the model's property 'name' and you will immediately see the view update itself, because it listens to the change event of the model.

more info on these events can be found here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events

Comment: the one thing that you are missing is how the whole asynchronous model plays into this. e.g. http://quickleft.com/blog/leveraging-deferreds-in-backbonejs but apparently there are problems with that model. how do you go about the asynchronous loading bit?

Comment: it is in there :), take a close look at `m.fetch()`... that launches a call to the server (trough the url defined in the model) your server side can look any way you like, it just needs to return a model, i can't show you server side code as i don't know what server technology you will use,  asp.net, php, node.js, ...